# Angular js select default dropdown menu value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using angular js, I want the service2 value to be selected by default in the dropdown menu.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ssFHZEBuYWPUACEJ5GTb?p=preview

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
  <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v.name for v in prop.values">
  </select>

  {{ prop.value.name}}
{{ prop.value.id}}
</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
 function MyCntrl($scope) {
      $scope.prop = {   "type": "select", 
        "name": "Service",
        "value":{"id":2, "name": "Service 2" }, 
    "values": [ {"id":1, "name": "Service 1" }, {"id":2, "name": "Service 2" }, {"id":3, "name": "Service 3" }, {"id":4, "name": "Service 4" }] 
      };

}
```

Here is what i want to achieve:
1) Change the selected object id and name
2) Select a value by default and display its id and name

In the example the id and name of the second service is well displayed. However, The dropdown menu fails to select the service 2.

How can I fix this ?

Regards

Comment: Did you get it sorted?? You got answers you could respond to!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you really using angular 1.0? If you can use Angular >= 1.2 just use `track by` feature:

```
<select ng-model="prop.value" ng-options="v.name for v in prop.values track by v.id">
```

Example: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E6Md9U5d2y52dug7pkOe?p=preview)

Resource:
[Documentation for ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need,

```
    <select ng-model="prop.value" ng-init="prop.value = prop.values[1]"
      ng-options="v.name for v in prop.values">
```

Note the `ng-init` part, where the `select` option is initialized with the 2nd item of the dropdown or rather the `prop.values` array.

I hope this is what you had asked for.